# Unity: Moving a sprite to coordinate (tween)

Tags: c#, unityscript

I'm new to Unity C#, and have tried to get a simple sprite to move to i.e. coordinates 3,5 ; 4,5. I cannot make this work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have tried the following:

```
public class Zookeeper : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 50f;
    private Vector2 target;

    void Start () {
        target = transform.position;
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(
            transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: I have tried the following script - but I do not understand how/where to enter actual coordinates http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14279/make-an-object-move-from-point-a-to-point-b-then-b.html

Comment: OK, and what have **you** written? Please include **your** code in the above post. (Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39486529/edit).) Looking at that example, it seems to be a simple matter of calling `transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i)` - so we need to see what exactly you're struggling with. Are you mis-defining the sprite and/or vectors? Are you failing to include some libraries? We need more information in order to provide a good answer. See: [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you - I've written the code above - my question is based on the fact that I want to indicate the coordinates. IE. Goto(10,10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `Start` method to something like this:

```
    void Start () 
    {
        target = new Vector2(3.5f, 4.5f);
    }
```

You need to operate with `target` to make it move where you want.

Comment: THANK YOU - it was the declaration of the Vector I could not get around :-)

Comment: @edutainPeople if it helped you tick the answer.

Comment: Where can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start() {
    target = new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y);
}
```

This Sets the target to the object, the script is assigned. But you clod just use

```
transform.position.x
```

Or

```
transform.position.y
```